# Use Android libraries into a java class/console program

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have an Android application that uses classes like *android.graphics.Bitmap* and *android.content.Context*. I would like to use this code into a small Java console application, and because there is a lot of code written in this Android app using those libraries, rewrite this code into a new Java class is something that can't be done at this moment.

I would like to know what options I have here. I was thinking about:

- import the Android library into my Java class console application and use the Android libraries/methods/functions there (don't know if it is possible);
- pack the Android application into a .jar file (or something like that) and import this package/use the class methods into my console application (almost the same above);
- expose a method in the Android application to be used like an service (of course that this is not possible, but commenting here to illustrate the requirement);
- any other way to reuse the code written into the Android app without have to rewrite the code into the new Java console application;

The idea is, as cited above, not rewrite the code. The code at the Android app is in use for three years and works like a charm.

Do you guys know if there is a way to accomplish this? Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use an Android Context in a vanilla java application?

Comment: Sorry, Android Context was only one example. There are other libraries in use at the Android app, but those libs will be removed. The main requirement is really the _android.graphics.Bitmap_... If I can use the _android.graphics.Bitmap_ with the Java console application, the problem is probably solved. Any ideia? Thank you for your reply.